# away3d global coordinates?

Tags: away3d

How can I refer to global coordinates of an aboject? like in PV3D was for example object.sceneZ

x, y, z in Away3d return coordinates to object display container, there is a way to retrieve the global coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a look at the docs and saw the [sceneTransform](http://away3d.com/livedocs/3.6.0_lib/away3d/core/base/Object3D.html#sceneTransform) property which is a Matrix3D instance, so you can access the global coordinates through the sceneTransforms' [position](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html#position) property.

I would imagine it would something like:

```
trace(yourObject3D.sceneTransform.position);//a Vector3D instance
```

I haven't tried this, but it should work (famous last words :) )